# Is the second order difference quotient jointly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity, mean-value-theorem

Suppose that we have a differentiable function $f\colon I\to\mathbb{R}$ on some interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$. The difference quotient of $f$ is defined by
$$\Delta_{f}\colon I\times I\to\mathbb{R},\qquad\Delta_{f}(x,y):=\begin{cases}\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} & x\not=y \\ & \\ f'(x)=f'(y) & x=y\end{cases}.$$
It is clear that $\Delta_{f}$ is *separately continuous* by definition of differentiability.

> (*) According to [this webpage](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Difference_quotient), $\Delta_{f}$ is *jointly continuous* if and only if $f'$ is continuous (i.e. $f$ is C${}^{1}$).

Now assume that $f$ is twice differentiable and define the second order difference quotient of $f$ by
$$\Delta_{f}^{2}\colon I\times I\to\mathbb{R},\qquad\Delta_{f}^{2}(x,y):=\begin{cases}\dfrac{f'(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}}{x-y} & x\not=y \\ & \\ \tfrac{1}{2}f''(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}f''(y) & x=y\end{cases},$$
where the factor $\tfrac{1}{2}$ is "justified" by Taylor's theorem. I was wondering if (*) generalizes as follows.

> (**) Is it true that $\Delta_{f}^{2}$ is jointly continuous if and only if $f''$ is continuous (i.e. $f$ is C${}^{2}$)?

In a similar fashion one can define $\Delta_{f}^{k}$ and ask whether $\Delta_{f}^{k}$ is jointly continuous if and only if $f$ is C${}^{k}$. However, if the $k=2$ case is true, then I suspect that the general case can be proven inductively.

Comment: It's obvious from definition that $\Delta^2_f$ is continuous only if $f$ is $C^2$. For the "if" part, it's a corollary of Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder ). Your case is $k=1$ in wikipedia notation.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks for your response. One can use Taylor's theorem to deduce separate continuity. However, joint continuity (which is stronger than separate continuity) is not that obvious, I think.

Comment: Pick a sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to (a,b)$. If $a\ne b$ there is nothing to prove. If $a=b$, we can without loss of generality restrict to the case where $x_n\ne y_n$ for all $n$. Consider a sequence $\{\xi_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\min\{x_n,y_n\}<\xi_n< \max\{y_n,x_n\}$ and $\frac12f''(\xi_n)(y_n-x_n)^2=f(y_n)-f(x_n)-f'(x_n)(y_n-x_n)$, which exists by Taylor. The RHS is by definition $(y_n-x_n)^2\Delta_f^2(x_n,y_n)$; since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_n=a$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta^2_f(x_n,y_n)=\frac12f''(a)$. QED